# How to debug Thunar Custom Action

Tags: thunar

Some Thunar Custom Action that I thought would work (namely, opening multiple folders with Sublime Text), doesn't work.

However, finding what is it that gone wrong is quite hard, since there is no output, even in terminal.

What can I do to get information on a failing Thunar Custom Action?

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to the party but I just ran into this. To see the output of the command, you can pipe it into [`zenity`](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/) like this:

```
command | zenity --text-info
```

If you want to see errors, you can redirect stderr to stdout like this:

```
command 2>&1 | zenity --text-info
```